# How can I control commenting in Sublime Text 2 when compiling SCSS?

Tags: sass, sublimetext2

I just installed the TextMate SCSS bundle for Sublime Text 2. It's compiling just fine but my issue is that it's adding a comment like `/*line 1, ../scss/style.scss  */` before every rule. It's a bit much. How can I control that?

Comment: Do you mean [this package](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SCSS)?

Comment: Do you have any other plugins installed for building your SCSS files? The bundle you referenced does not have any build functionality, so the issue must be with another plugin.

Comment: Yes, I also have SCSS Snippets installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the resolution. I didn't think to mention that I'm using Scout App to compile my CSS. I needed to switch the output mode from Development to Production.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your config.rb file and look at the settings for `line_comments` (or `line_numbers`) and possibly `output_style`. You probably want:

```
line_comments = false
```

but check out http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#line_numbers-option to figure out exactly what you want those configurations to be.

Comment: I don't see a config.rb file anywhere. Even did a search for it with no results. Where would that file be? Thanks.

Comment: It's usually in the directory where your web project is - but it depends on how you (our your config stuff) set it up.